# How to compare two spark datasets

Tags: unit-testing, apache-spark, bigdata, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

I was trying to test the structured streaming joins in spark 3.2.2. So i have two files which i am reading as a stream and then joining them on some already defined condition as

```java
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local")
    .appName("streamstreamJoinTest").getOrCreate();
spark.sparkContext().setLogLevel("WARN");
Dataset<Row> adClickDF = spark
    .readStream()
    .format("json")
    .schema(Schema.getSchema("adClick_flow"))
    .option("path","D:/Users/subodh.k/IdeaProjects/spark/src/test/sources/adClickFlowTest/")
    .load()
    .withColumnRenamed("time_stamp","adClick_flow_time");
assert(adClickDF.isStreaming());
Dataset<Row> prebidRADF = spark
     .readStream()
     .format("json")
     .schema(Schema.getSchema("prebidRenderedStream"))
     .option("path","D:/Users/subodh.k/IdeaProjects/spark/src/test/sources/prebidRATest/")
     .load()
     .withColumnRenamed("time_stamp","prebidRenderedStream_time");
assert(prebidRADF.isStreaming());
Dataset<Row>result = streamstreamJoin
    .performJoin(prebidRADF,adClickDF,"inner",config.getJoinCondition("prebidRenderedStream,adClick_flow"));
result = result
     .drop(functions.col("adClick_flow_time"))
     .drop(functions.col("prebidRenderedStream_time"));
result.printSchema();
```

I have expected output inside a json file but now i am facing problems like how exactly to assert that the actual output (i.e. result stream) is same as expected result.

So i read somewhere that there are some restrictions on streaming sources so i decided to overwrite writestream function using forEatchBatch. here it is-

```java
Dataset<Row> expectedResult =spark
    .read()
    .schema(Schema.getSchema("join_test"))
    .json("./src/test/sources/result");
expectedResult.show();
expectedResult.printSchema();

result.writeStream()
    .foreachBatch(new VoidFunction2<Dataset<Row>, Long>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Dataset<Row> rowDataset, Long aLong) throws Exception {
            rowDataset.persist();
            rowDataset.write().format("json").save("./src/test/sources/out");  // location 1
            rowDataset.show();
            boolean isEqual=(rowDataset.schema()==expectedResult.schema());
//          boolean isEqual=(rowDataset.union(expectedResult) == rowDataset.intersect(expectedResult));
            System.out.println(isEqual);
            assertTrue(isEqual);
            rowDataset.unpersist();
        }
    }).start().awaitTermination();
spark.stop();
```

In this case even the schema is not matching, but you can see the output that they are identical.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|            prvReqId|              requrl|      cid|commit_id|customer_id|       publisher_url|            click_id|creative_id|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|20921422925761_25...|https://www.sluur...|8CU2IW465| af5ccafa|  8CU7FAK9R|https://www.sluur...|1688231161658223d...|  718736355|
|20115773235743_19...|https://www.sluur...|8CU2IW465| af5ccafa|  8CU7FAK9R|https://www.sluur...|1688231161658223d...|  718736355|
|20921422925761_25...|https://www.sluur...|8CU2IW465| af5ccafa|  8CU7FAK9R|https://www.sluur...|1688231161658223d...|  718736355|
|20115773235743_19...|https://www.sluur...|8CU2IW465| af5ccafa|  8CU7FAK9R|https://www.sluur...|1688231161658223d...|  718736355|
|18502652846296_19...|https://www.daily...|8CUSRVM5T| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|21515713386847_79...|https://www.daily...|8CUSRVM5T| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|285048723281047_2...|https://www.daily...|8CUYAT8I3| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|18502652846296_19...|https://www.daily...|8CUSRVM5T| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|21515713386847_79...|https://www.daily...|8CUSRVM5T| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|285048723281047_2...|https://www.daily...|8CUYAT8I3| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|18502652846296_19...|https://www.daily...|8CUSRVM5T| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|21515713386847_79...|https://www.daily...|8CUSRVM5T| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|285048723281047_2...|https://www.daily...|8CUYAT8I3| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+

root
 |-- prvReqId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- requrl: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- commit_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- customer_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publisher_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- click_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- creative_id: string (nullable = true)

requrl=publisher_url AND prebidRenderedStream_time <=  adClick_flow_time AND prebidRenderedStream_time + interval 10 minute > adClick_flow_time 
root
 |-- prvReqId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- requrl: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- commit_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- customer_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publisher_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- click_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- creative_id: string (nullable = true)

23/07/03 12:38:39 WARN ResolveWriteToStream: Temporary checkpoint location created which is deleted normally when the query didn't fail: D:\Users\subodh.k\AppData\Local\Temp\1\temporary-81996e77-70da-4968-adcb-dea49ad662b4. If it's required to delete it under any circumstances, please set spark.sql.streaming.forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation to true. Important to know deleting temp checkpoint folder is best effort.
23/07/03 12:38:39 WARN ResolveWriteToStream: spark.sql.adaptive.enabled is not supported in streaming DataFrames/Datasets and will be disabled.
23/07/03 12:38:42 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
+--------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|            prvReqId|              requrl|      cid|commit_id|customer_id|       publisher_url|            click_id|creative_id|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|20921422925761_25...|https://www.sluur...|8CU2IW465| af5ccafa|  8CU7FAK9R|https://www.sluur...|1688231161658223d...|  718736355|
|20115773235743_19...|https://www.sluur...|8CU2IW465| af5ccafa|  8CU7FAK9R|https://www.sluur...|1688231161658223d...|  718736355|
|20921422925761_25...|https://www.sluur...|8CU2IW465| af5ccafa|  8CU7FAK9R|https://www.sluur...|1688231161658223d...|  718736355|
|20115773235743_19...|https://www.sluur...|8CU2IW465| af5ccafa|  8CU7FAK9R|https://www.sluur...|1688231161658223d...|  718736355|
|18502652846296_19...|https://www.daily...|8CUSRVM5T| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|21515713386847_79...|https://www.daily...|8CUSRVM5T| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|285048723281047_2...|https://www.daily...|8CUYAT8I3| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|18502652846296_19...|https://www.daily...|8CUSRVM5T| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|21515713386847_79...|https://www.daily...|8CUSRVM5T| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|285048723281047_2...|https://www.daily...|8CUYAT8I3| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|18502652846296_19...|https://www.daily...|8CUSRVM5T| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|21515713386847_79...|https://www.daily...|8CUSRVM5T| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
|285048723281047_2...|https://www.daily...|8CUYAT8I3| af5ccafa|  8CU161VUM|https://www.daily...|168823129190822wb...|  867420183|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+

false
```

Then i tried another approach that is write the stream in a file and then compare this file with the expectedoutput file. But writing a stream output in a specefic file is not supported as i far as i know. It is treating the path (where the output has to be written) as a directory and then in that directory i don't know how to retrieve the file in which actually the data has been written using java as the filename depends on the batchid or offset ig.

I want to check if the result from joining is actually the same as expected result. So please suggest me a way to do it. I am an intern and new to actual corporate programming and hence do not know much about unit testing. So if my approach is wrong in unit testing then, you can also let me know a better approach to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
if (firstDataFrame.exceptAll(secondDataFrame).head(1).isEmpty) {
//The two DF are equals, process here
} else {
//There is difference
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check the output, why not waiting from the streaming job to consume everything, and then compare the output with the expected ?

In pseudo code:

```
streamingjob.write("out")
// wait termination
expectedDs = load("expected")
resultDs = load("out")
// check results
expectedDs.schema == resultDs.schema && expectedDs.collect() == resultDs.collect()
```

Just make sure to use `Trigger.AvailableNow()` , so it will stop automatically when all the content is consumed.

```
df.writeStream(...).trigger(Trigger.AvailableNow()).start()
```

Note that you can also just use any file reader to check the result, you don't need to go through spark loading into datasets to compare.

See more: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers

Comment: It is a streaming source so i don't think if there is a way to stop this query after completion of first batch as it will keep checking for new data. So that's why i used this way so that after completion of first batch and after passing the assertion condition i can just call System.exit().

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a file being your input in a streaming context, this file has a limited content, then you can just apply the trigger on the available data only and it will stop on its own when it consumed all content, so when starting the stream use this trigger:

`df.writeStream ... .trigger(Trigger.AvailableNow()).start()`
Then when the job is finished, you can compare as I mentioned.
See more: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers

Comment: Oh thanks you solved my problem. I am actually using my approach as it requires less file reads but was facing issue that how to terminate once i am done with processing data and now it is solved.

Comment: My pleasure ! Feel free to up my answer if it helped :)